# XCODE 8 xcuitest code generation compilation error

Tags: xctest

I have downloaded the xcode 8, and tried to record a test in xcuitest

but the generated code by xcode gives compilation error

Generated code

```
window.tables.children(matching: .tableRow).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 5).click()
```

Error 
but it is giving compilation error like Value of type 
'XCUIElementQuery' has no member ‘containing’
'XCUIElementQuery' has no member ‘ children’
'XCUIElementQuery' has no member ‘ matching’
'XCUIElementQuery' has no member ‘ element'

also .other should be changed to .Other
.cell should be changed to .Cell to fix the error

i selected swift 2.3 while installing xcode 8

Any help appreciated

Comment: Any one had the same issue?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code generator migrated to a new sytnax for the call to the children, but not the code interpreter. Replace .children(matching: .cell) with childrenMatchingType(.Cell)

Comment: Yes that is a workaround and we are doing that. but it is a double work. Is there any permanent solution.

Comment: @VijayakumarKb I filed a radar with apple about it. It might be helpful for you to file one as well.